# How to efficiently find the optimal path along a tree

Tags: python, graph-theory

I have a tree structure where each node has three choices (1, 2, 3), and there are 100 layers.

```
 Layer 1             1                      2                3
                /    |     \
               /     |      \
              /      |       \
             /       |        \
Layer 2     1        2         3
          / | \    / | \     / | \   
Layer 3  1  2  3  1  2  3   1  2  3   ...
...
```

Each choice gives certain payoff. I want to go through each choice path (from top to bottom) and find the highest total/accumulated payoffs of all the actions in a path out of all the paths. I only need the highest payoff but not the path.

A complication is that the payoff of each choice depends on choice in the previous node.
Is there a more efficient way to find the highest payoff than using `for` loop?

Here is my attempt where I simply the calculations of the payoffs.

```
import numpy as np

# number of layers
num_periods = 2

def get_payoffs(p):
    payoffs = np.array([[12, 6, 10],
                        [10, 24, 14],
                        [6, 10, 30]])
    return payoffs @ p

def get_prob(payoffs):
    nom = np.exp(payoffs)
    return nom/nom.sum()

p0 = np.eye(3)
p = p0
accumulated_payoffs = [0]
t = 1
while t<=num_periods:
    for i in range(len(accumulated_payoffs)):
        current_payoffs=[]
        for action in range(0,3):
            payoffs = get_payoffs(p[action])
            p[action]=get_prob(payoffs)
            current_payoffs.extend(payoffs+accumulated_payoffs[i])
        accumulated_payoffs[i] = current_payoffs
        t+=1
print(accumulated_payoffs)
```

Comment: `for` loops are not inherently inefficient; as you haven't posted *your* `for` loop, can't comment on how much more efficient it could be.

Comment: "I want to find the path" seems to contradict "I only need the highest payoff but not the path"; also you haven't explained how "total payoffs" are computed.

Comment: And without knowing how this tree is represented, how can one possibly talk about code to do anything with it?

Comment: If by `for` loop you mean visiting each node, that'll probably be unavoidable unless add more information from your domain. A node representing a doomed game state might be safely ignored, but if there's even a slight chance of a sufficiently large child creating a large payout, you'll have to visit all nodes.

Comment: Hi. Could you please give a bit more information about your situation? In particular I have the following questions: Is the "total payoff of a path" the sum of the individual payoffs of the nodes in that path? Have you heard about generic tree-exploring techniques called "depth-first-search" and "breadth-first-search"?

Comment: In addition to the other comments: what have you tried so far? This is a Q&A website, not a "write my code" or "solve my problem" site.

Answer (score 0):

In O(n):

Run BFS from the root. keep track of the cumulative payoff of each node. The cumulative payoff of each node is just it's payoff added to its parent's cumulative payoff.

Keep track of the highest cumulative payoff you've seen, and return this at the end.

This is O(n) since BFS is O(n) on a tree, and you can't do better since you need to look at every node or you might miss a big outlier that changes the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using dynamic programming. The idea is to store the maximum payoff for each node, starting from the bottom of the tree and working your way up. Here's a high-level overview:

1.Create an array `dp` of size `n` (where `n` is the number of nodes), initialized with the payoffs of the nodes at the bottom level of the tree.

2.For each node at level `i` from the bottom of the tree (starting from `i=n-2` and going down to `0`), calculate the maximum payoff by considering all possible choices at the current node and the corresponding payoffs stored in `dp` for the next level. Store this maximum payoff in `dp[i]`.

3.The maximum total payoff is stored in `dp[0]`.

This avoids the need to traverse all paths in the tree, and instead calculates the maximum payoff in `O(n)` time